# Get rid of branch and bad code with Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I'm working on a new branch. Basically I've messed my code up and would like to go back to master and start fresh from a new branch.

Would `$ git revert` get me back to the master?

or should I be doing the following:

```
$ git branch -D branch-name
```

I want to get rid all the code and current entire branch that is checked out.

The online documentation is a bit confusing - scared to mess everything up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get back to the `master` branch simply use:

```
git checkout master
```

If you also want to blow away uncommitted changes you can follow that with:

```
git reset --hard
```

You can remove the unwanted branch using:

```
git branch -D branch-name
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `git branch -D branch-name` would delete the given branch. The commits would remain in the repository until garbage-collected. Make sure that you don't have that branch checked out when you delete it. To do so, just check out master again with `git checkout master`, then you can run the delete command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go back to master, just type in this:

```
git checkout master
```

Then start a new branch from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d messed-up-branch-name-goes-here
```

Other information may be found [at the git book](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: `git checkout -b master` is likely to fail because it would attempt to create a new branch named `master` which should already exist. Even if that worked, the new branch would have the current state which was undesired.